# `get_terms()` with `child_of` and `childless` combined

Tags: taxonomy, terms, children

I have a hierarchical taxonomy `filter` that contains locations and genres for posts with the custom type `artist`:

```
- Genre
-- Hip Hop
-- Trap
-- Rap
- Location
-- Europe
--- Germany
--- Sweden
--- Austria
-- Asia
--- China
--- Japan
--- Taiwan
```

Now I would like to use get_terms() to only get the Countries (children of 'Location' without children of their own). I thought this should work:

```
$location_parent = get_term(123, 'filter');

$countries = get_terms(array(
  'taxonomy' => $location_parent->taxonomy,
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'child_of' => $location_parent->term_id, 
  'childless' => true
));
```

...but it somehow doesn't. `child_of` and `childless` seem to get in each other's way. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure having a single filter taxonomy is wise? A `genre` and `location` taxonomy would be better, looking at your hierarchy though, could you just tell it not to recurse down and ignore children? Or use more than one request? This is probably one of those situations were the real problem is that you're asking too much of 1 function call and you're in need of multiple steps

Comment: You are wrong with your thoughts:
- Taxonomy is not "Location", Taxonomy is the name of your Custom Tax like category, post_tag, ... What's the name of your taxonomy?
- What's is $location var?

Comment: @TomJNowell, yes, usually that would be right. But in this particular case I can't use multiple taxonomies. Just expected `childless` and `child_of` to work together, don't you think?

Comment: @IvanMunoz The taxonomy is `filter`, not `location`. I will edit my question so this becomes clearer.

Comment: @TomJNowell can you explain a bit further what you mean by "just tell it not to recurse down and ignore children"?

Comment: I know it's `filter`, but this taxonomy is really 2 taxonomies smushed together, it would have been better as 2 separate taxonomies. Keep in mind that if you ask for all terms that have the parent "Europe", you'll get countries in Europe, but you won't get any sub-terms such as counties/provinces/etc, because their parent ID is not Europe. So you don't need to tell it not to look several levels deeper because it won't do that to begin with

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this is what I came up with:

```
function get_childless_term_children( $parent_id, $taxonomy ) {
  // get all childless $terms of this $taxonomy
  $terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'childless' => true,
  ));

  foreach( $terms as $key => $term ) {
    // remove $terms that aren't descendants (= children) of $parent_id
    if( !in_array( $parent_id, get_ancestors( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) ) {
      unset( $terms[$key] );
    }
  }
  return $terms;
}
```

What this does: Get all childless terms that are children of `$parent_id`.

Answer (score 0):

**childless** means:

(boolean) Returns terms that have no children if taxonomy is hierarchical, all terms if taxonomy is not hierarchical

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Function_Reference/get_terms

I think you're finding something like this:

```
/**
 * Recursively get taxonomy hierarchy
 *
 * @source http://www.daggerhart.com/wordpress-get-taxonomy-hierarchy-including-children/
 * @param string $taxonomy
 * @param int    $parent - parent term id
 *
 * @return array
 */
function get_taxonomy_hierarchy( $taxonomy, $parent = 0 ) {
    // only 1 taxonomy
    $taxonomy = is_array( $taxonomy ) ? array_shift( $taxonomy ) : $taxonomy;
    // get all direct decendents of the $parent
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array('parent' => $parent) );
    // prepare a new array.  these are the children of $parent
    // we'll ultimately copy all the $terms into this new array, but only after they
    // find their own children
    $children = array();
    // go through all the direct decendents of $parent, and gather their children
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        // recurse to get the direct decendents of "this" term
        $term->children = get_taxonomy_hierarchy( $taxonomy, $term->term_id );
        // add the term to our new array
        $children[ $term->term_id ] = $term;
    }
    // send the results back to the caller
    return $children;
}
```

It should return all the child from Location

We are agree?

Comment: This gives me all terms with their children. What I need is all terms that *don't* have children.